# the gradient of the product of a scalar by a vector

Tags: vector-analysis

We know from the tensor calculus that: $\vec\nabla (a\cdot b) = b\vec\nabla a + a \vec\nabla b$ , where $a$ and $b$ are two scalar functions.

But in the case where for example $a$ is a scalar function and $b$ is a vector how to develop that expression of gradient?
$$\vec{\nabla}\left(a\cdot \vec v \right) = ?$$

Comment: Two possible meanings. If there is no [dot-product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) between $\vec{\nabla}$ and $a\vec{v}$ then you are taking the gradient of a vector-field. This is [answered here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156880/gradient-of-a-vector-field). If there is a dot-product between $\vec{\nabla}$ and $a\vec{v}$ then you are taking the [divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence) of $a\vec{v}$ and you can find the relevant formula [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence#Properties).

Comment: thanks, I mean the gradient of a vector field, I know how to do that for a vector field, but it seems hard when that vector is multiplied by a scalar function

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These sort of identities are usually proved in the component form and then transferred back to component-free form. In view of this, note that $\nabla(a\boldsymbol{v})$ is a second order tensor. Thus using the product rule,

$$\left(\nabla(a\boldsymbol{v})\right)_{ij} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\left(av_i\right)=\frac{\partial a}{\partial x_j}v_i+a\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_j}.$$

From the above component form, it is recognized that

$$\nabla(a\boldsymbol{v}) = \boldsymbol{v}\otimes\nabla a + a\nabla\boldsymbol{v}.$$

Comment: Great. Glad I could help.

Comment: Post another question and I'll be happy to answer it. That way the answer will be easier to find if others also have the same question.

Comment: $(\text{div}(\vec{v}\otimes\vec{v}))_i=\tfrac{\partial}{\partial x_j}(v_iv_j)=\tfrac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_j}v_j+v_i\tfrac{\partial v_j}{\partial x_j}$. Thus, $$\text{div}(\vec{v}\otimes\vec{v}) = (\nabla\vec{v})\vec{v}+(\text{div}\,\vec{v})\vec{v}.$$

Comment: are you sure about this term: $\left( \nabla\vec v \right) \vec v$ I think there is a dot product between $\left( \nabla \vec v \right) $ and $\vec v$

Comment: Some people put a dot between the two; it is a matter of notational preference. What is meant is the second order tensor $\nabla\vec{v}$ acting on the vector $\vec{v}$. This produces a vector.

Comment: thank you for the reply. but, between the gradient of $\vec v$ (which a 2nd order tensor) and $\vec v$ is there a dot?

Comment: When a second order tensor $\boldsymbol{A}$ acts on a vector $\vec{x}$, I write $\boldsymbol{A}\vec{x}$. You can think of this like a matrix times a vector. In components, this is $\left(\boldsymbol{A}\vec{x}\right)_{ij} = A_{ij}x_j$. This is what is going on in the term $(\nabla\vec{v})\vec{v}$.

Comment: Would it be possible to show why not $\nabla a\otimes\vec v$ for the first term in the right? I cannot convince myself that my own derivation was something wrong, so I have asked a new question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4213636