# Computing the gradient of the following function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Let
$$
f(x_1,x_2) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+1}} \left(x_1,x_2,1 \right)
$$

For $i = 1,2$ we have

$$
\partial_{x_i} f = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+1}}\left(\partial_{x_i}x_1,\partial_{x_i}x_2,0 \right) +\frac{-x_i}{\left(x_1^2+x_2^2+1\right)^{3/2}}(x_1,x_2,1) =
\frac{1}{\left(x_1^2+x_2^2+1\right)^{3/2}} \left[\left(x_1^2+x_2^2+1\right)\left(\partial_{x_i}x_1,\partial_{x_i}x_2,0\right) - x_i(x_1,x_2,1) \right]
$$

The gradient of such function, after some computation I get the following matrix

$$
\nabla f =
\frac{1}{\left(x_1^2+x_2^2+1\right)^{3/2}} 
\begin{pmatrix}
x_2^2+1 & - x_1x_2 & -x_1 \\
-x_1x_2 & x_1^2+1 & -x_2
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Is it correct?

Comment: the gradient is not a matrix. Maybe you mean the jacobian matrix.

Comment: The gradient is a matrix if your function is a vector, which is my case.

Comment: @Masacroso: tha gradient of a vector function is an standard definition in some contexts. (eres el mismo del rincon?)

Comment: @Masacroso It's not my language... https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156880/gradient-of-a-vector-field, this guy calls "gradient" essentially the same thing.

Comment: @user8469759 alright, first time I heard of it

Answer (score 1):

The calculus of the partial derivates are correct. But the definition that I know of the matrix gradient is the transpose matrix that you wrote.

Comment: I think that depends from how you consider vectors, right? (If rows or columns)

Comment: In definition that I know, the gradient of a vector function $f$ is a matrix which rows are the gradient of the components of $f$, so the gradient is the same matrix if $f$ is a row or a column vector. But you must to revise the definition that you are using.

Comment: Actually I'm not using any definition. I'll check later my analysis book.

Comment: @yemino I saw sometimes multivariable calculus written as $xA$ instead of $Ax$, for some jacobian matrix $A$. It is rare (as rare as call "gradient" to the jacobian matrix :p) but exists. Im the same guy of the rincon.