# What are the Effects of Applying the $\nabla$ Operator to a Scalar Field?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis, divergence-operator, scalar-fields, curl

For a scalar field $f(\mathbf{r})$, where $\mathbf{r} = (x, y, z)$, what kind of mathematical object results from each of the operations below:

$$ \nabla f(\textbf{r}) $$

$$ \nabla \cdot f(\textbf{r}) $$

$$ \nabla \times f(\textbf{r})? $$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the first, you get a vector representing how fast $f$ changes in each direction. The second two expressions are not defined, because you can only dot or cross a vector *with another vector*. Here is a table of the "possibilities", where $f$ is a scalar field, and $\mathbf{F}$ is a vector field:
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline
\text{Operation} &\text{Result} \\ \hline
\nabla f &\text{vector field} \\ \hline
\nabla \cdot f & \text{undefined} \\ \hline
\nabla \times f & \text{undefined} \\ \hline
\nabla\mathbf{F} &\text{tensor} \\ \hline
\nabla \cdot\mathbf{F} & \text{scalar} \\ \hline
\nabla\times\mathbf{F} & \text{vector} \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$
For a reference on the expression $\nabla\mathbf{F}$, see [this M.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156880/gradient-of-a-vector-field), and [this wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_derivative_(continuum_mechanics)#Curvilinear_coordinates) to which it links.

Comment: So the first one is valid for nabla operator, and the other two are valid if nabla is a vector?

Comment: Nabla is *always* a vector. The result of nabla applied to anything is another vector. Your second two expressions are only valid when nabla is operating on a *vector* field. That is, you can write $\nabla\cdot\mathbf{F}$ or $\nabla\times\mathbf{E}$, where the $\mathbf{F}$ and $\mathbf{E}$ are *vector* fields.

Comment: OK, that makes more sense. Thanks

Comment: You're very welcome!

Comment: Nabla is not a vector (at least not the same kind as $\mathbf r$), but you can pretend that it is for many purposes.

Comment: @amd: Right - it's technically a vector operator. But I find that for students, thinking of it primarily as a vector is more helpful.

Comment: @Rob Ch: I made a mistake in a previous comment: $\nabla\cdot\mathbf{F}$ is a scalar. I had said that nabla applied to anything is another vector, which is not true.

Answer (score 2):

The gradient operator $\nabla$ takes a scalar function $f:\mathbf{R}^3 \to \mathbf{R}$ and produces a vector field $(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}).$ The notation $\nabla \cdot F$ denotes the application of $\nabla$ componentwise on the components of a vector field $\mathbf{R}^3\to \mathbf{R}^3$, and describes the divergence. For instance, if the vector field is 
$$ F(x,y,z)=P(x,y,z)i+Q(x,y,z)j+R(x,y,z),$$
the divergence operator gives us 
$$ \nabla\cdot F(x,y,z)=\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}(x,y,z)+\frac{\partial Q}{\partial y}(x,y,z)+\frac{\partial R}{\partial z}(x,y,z).$$
In particular, this quantity lives in $\mathbf{R}$. However, the divergence operator needs to act on a vector field to be meaningful. In the case where $f:\mathbf{R}^3\to \mathbf{R}$ is a scalar field, there is not a good idea of what that would mean. For the last case, we have the standard curl operator $\nabla\times F$ where $F$ is as above. It is given by 
$$ \nabla\times F=\bigg(\frac{\partial R}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial Q}{\partial z}\bigg)i+\bigg(\frac{\partial P}{\partial z}-\frac{\partial R}{\partial x}\bigg)j+\bigg(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\bigg)k.$$
As we can see, this eats a vector field $F:\mathbf{R}^3\to\mathbf{R}^3$ and produces a vector field in $\mathbf{R}^3$. In your case, it is not obvious how to apply $\nabla\times f$ where $f$ is a scalar field, because the curl depends on the cross product in its definition, which is a construction special to $\mathbf{R}^3$.

In summation, the only one of these expressions that is well-defined is the first.