# If gradient at a point defines a hyperplane, what does a Jacobian define?

Tags: calculus, geometry, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, euclidean-geometry

A (normalized) gradient vector $\hat{g}$ at a point $x$ defines a hyperplane. Given a vector $v$ the operator below reflects it against the hyperplane
$$
R(v, \hat{g}) = v - 2\hat{g}\hat{g}^\top v
$$

[image]

Now suppose I have a Jacobian matrix $J_f$ instead of a gradient vector. What is the generalization of this operation?

## My Attempt

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ be a function such that $f(x) = (f_1(x), \ldots, f_m(x))^\top$. Its Jacobian is a matrix
$$
J_f(x) = \begin{pmatrix}
    \nabla f_1(x)^\top \\
\vdots \\
    \nabla f_m(x)^\top 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Now each of its rows could be used to do a reflection with respect to that gradient $R(v, \widehat{\nabla f}_i(x))$, as shown in the picture above. However, I would like to *generalize* this operation to the whole Jacobian.

#### Idea 1

One way I thought of doing this is by using the reflection with respect to each of the coordinates sequentially. That is I keep on iterating
$$
v \longleftarrow R(v, \widehat{\nabla f}_i(x))
$$
for $i=1, \ldots, m$. However the order in which you do this operation seems to matter.

#### Idea 2

Perhaps rather than reflecting against each gradient, one could sum up all the gradients, normalize and reflect against a "mean" gradient? That is one would compute
$$
\overline{\nabla f}(x) = \sum_{i=1}^m \nabla f_i(x)
$$
then normalize it and compute $R(v, \widehat{\overline{\nabla f}})$

Comment: The Jacobian being a matrix, its kernel defines a linear subspace. Since the Jacobian of a numerical function can be identified with its gradient by $df(v) = \langle \nabla f, v\rangle$, these two objects reflects the same thing

Comment: @Didier Thank you for the comment. I am a bit confused (mainly because I am misunderstanding something). Suppose $h:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$. Then the gradient $g(x) = \nabla h(x)$ is in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $R(v, \hat{g})$ describes the reflection of $v$ with respect to the tangent space of $h$ at $x$.
$$

$$
Now for $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ the Jacobian is a matrix $J_f\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$. I am not sure what mathematical object this matrix defines. What do you mean by $\nabla h(x)^\top v$?

Comment: I said that they coincide for numerical function, that is function with values in $\Bbb R$. Of course, the gradient is not defined for functions with values in greater dimensional spaces

Comment: @Didier I added some explanation in my post!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156880/what-does-it-mean-to-take-the-gradient-of-a-vector-field/4359170#4359170

Comment: The general notion is called [Householder transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation), where there is no "gradient vector", not even a map $f$.  What kind of generalization are you looking for?