# What is the process for applying the gradient to vectors?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity, partial-derivative

I am working through A Physical Introduction to Suspension Dynamics and the authors apply the continuity equation to a long equation (Equations 1 and 2) [image: Equation 1] [image: Equation 2] in order to reach the solution of Equation 3 [image: Equation 3]. I am only able to work out a part of how they reach Equation 3, but I can't work out how the λ2 term stays and the λ3 term disappears. I think I am misunderstanding how the gradient is applied to **x** and its components.
Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does it mean to take the gradient of a vector field?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156880/what-does-it-mean-to-take-the-gradient-of-a-vector-field)

Comment: Unfortunately I could not see from that answer how the λ3 term disappears.